# Is the comment/answer reputation reversed?

Tags: discussion, reputation

It appears that a user needs 150 rep to comment.  So I see a lot of new users posting their comments as answers because, what other choice do they have?  A user with less than 150 rep doesn't have the experience to *not* comment (as an answer).  So that leaves it to the mature community to clean up after these newbies with moderator flags.

Perhaps the reputation system should be reversed..
Make it take 150 rep to answer.  Comments can be made at any rep - perhaps not allowing external links in comments by users w/ less than 150 rep.  Comments earn rep at some rate.. say 2 pts per upvote per 24 hour period that the comment is available for viewing.  Only make comments earn rep for users with less than 150 rep.

That way you allow the community to choose when a user is mature enough to start posting answers.

** Replace all the numeric values with variables and tweak it to your heart's content.  I'm just proposing that the incentive be given to let newbies comment instead of posting comments as answers.

Comment: first of all it is 50 reputation for [comment everywhere](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Most of those NAA flags are handled in the review queues. Is it really that big of a problem.

Comment: And you gain rep from answers. You don't from comments.

Comment: Sounds like you are proposing to change SO from collection of good Q&A into more or less discussion forum with comments being important part of the content (which is opposite of how site is setup now). If not - make sure to clarify how your proposal deals with current state - "comments are ephemeral".

Comment: Sure.... Only comments till you get enough repto answer.... Comments don't give rep. Kudos for managing to make Stack even more hard to start on :p

Answer (score 10):

The purpose of having a minimum reputation to comment is to discourage people from commenting. And while there are new users who do post their comments as answers, there are plenty more who never attempt to post comments. As exemplified by the fact that users frequently come to MSO asking about how they can post comments on a question without the rep.

This is a Q&A site. We want to encourage questions and *answers*, not questions and comments. We do this by limiting the size of comments, limiting their editability, and getting new users used to the Q&A paradigm by preventing them from using the comment feature everywhere.

Your suggestion would encourage users to post answers as comments. That is *far* more detrimental to the purpose of the site than posting comments as answers.